# Remove fields not needed from date input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the following script to autofill an input date with current date/time

```
var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
document.getElementById("MyDate").value = today;
```

Output :

```
Date : 2022-03-09 11:39:19.000000,3,Europe/Berlin
```

Would it be possible to remove the timezone... etc.

So the output will look like :

```
Date : 2022-03-09 11:39:19
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: Note: even the developers of [tag:momentjs]  recommend that you don't use [tag:momentjs].  See [SO wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/momentjs/info) and [moment project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Comment: Your code, as provided, does not produce that output, as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/37fucxnd/   Please [edit] the question and add a snippet (click `[<>]`) and add just enough code to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment().utc() before format the date to have an universal date and then format it as expected

```js
var today = moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
document.getElementById("MyDate").value = today;
```

```html
<div>
  Date : <input id ="MyDate"/>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but the Output is : 2022-03-09 12:04:01.000000,3,Europe/Berlin

Comment: @FTKZBN that's not the output generated in the above snippet (for us at least) - though there is no real difference or "fix" in this snippet.   If your code is doing something different, then there must be something different *somewhere else* in your code, eg the html for your `input` or other element with id `MyDate`.  Please update your question with sample code if the linked question (not using momentjs) doesn't work for you.